# Steps to send recurring request to server after an interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

> My node.js program is making a request to a 3rd party API
>
> I want to have the code for a Node.js program be written in a way and be standardized for my team where:
>
> 1. an Http request is sent to a server
> 2. if after waiting for 500ms(just an example), end the request
> 3. retry sending another request automatically, retry 5 times only
> 4. if still no response from the server after 5 retries, send an appropriate message with 
>      res.status(500).send("No response from server")

Comment: Where is your code attempt?

Comment: As @Tom says, you should provide some code that you have attempted rather than asking an open-ended question with only requirements.  Show your work and others will help you get it right, but it is asking a lot for a request to "just write this for me".